# Custom beans in Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm looking for a way to share beans between two or more applications. I looked at Spring Cloud Config which seemed great, but I noticed it only shares properties and not beans.

Is there a way to store beans in Spring Cloud Config? Or can you suggest another solutions to beans sharing between remote apps?

Comment: Imagine the 2 applications work on different JVMs. Instead you can create a copy of bean. E.g. introduce a third project (let's name it common.jar) and place the common beans there. Then both apps can use the same common.js creating own copy of the same beans

Comment: Why not just create the beans in such a way you can externalize the configuration to a properties file and take advantage of Cloud Config? You'll end up coupling your apps together when introducing 3rd party utility/config jars which always end up becoming far more hassle than its worth.

Comment: @StanislavL I do that. But I want the configurations to be dynamic.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Good idea. Where can I find examples of that?
My beans have custom classes and lists and such. I wonder if it all will be fitted in properties.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Config was only ever meant to store properties, not beans.

Comment: Okay. Do you know of a framework which does the same thing for beans?

Comment: No, I do not know of one.